# Nesting asynchronous api calls in Async waterfall

Tags: node.js, express, request, node-async

I'm using async waterfall to make two API calls. The second call depends on data from the first one, so it is important that the first one finishes executing before the second one starts. However, in the following code snippet, the second function always starts before the first one finishes, therefore it never gets the data. How can I please fix this? Thanks!

```
 router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
  var campaign;
  var restaurant;
  async.waterfall([

    function(callback){
      var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/campaign";
      console.log("calling campaign");
      request(url, function(err, response, body) {
        // JSON body
        if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
        campaign = JSON.parse(body);

      }, callback(null, campaign));

    },
    function(obj, callback){
      console.log(obj.restaurant);
      var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/restaurantByID/"+obj.restaurant;
      console.log("calling restaurant");
      request(url, function(err, response, body) {
        // JSON body
        if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
        restaurant = JSON.parse(body);

      }, callback(null, restaurant));


    }
  ],
  function (err, result) {
   if(err) { console.log(err); res.send(500,"Server Error"); return; }

   res.render("home.html", {"title":"Home", "campaign": campaign, "restaurant": result});   
  });


});
```

**UPDATE 1**
I mistakenly placed the callback as third argument for request. I have fixed that but the code still does not behave as expected. Thanks

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
  var campaign;
  var restaurant;
  async.waterfall([

    function(callback){
      var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/campaign";
      console.log("calling campaign");
      request(url, function(err, response, body) {
        // JSON body
        if(err) { console.log(err);callback(true); return; }
        campaign = JSON.parse(body);
        callback(null, campaign.restaurant);
      });


    },
    function(restaurant, callback){
      console.log(restaurant);
      var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/restaurantByID/"+restaurant;
      console.log("calling restaurant");
      request(url, function(err, response, body) {
        // JSON body
        if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
        restaurant = JSON.parse(body);
        callback(null, restaurant);
      });


    }
  ],
  function (err, result) {
   if(err) { console.log(err); res.send(500,"Server Error"); return; }

   res.render("home.html", {"title":"Home", "campaign": campaign, "restaurant": result});   
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `request` takes in a 3rd argument as a function.  Try calling it inside the callback, instead of as an argument like below:

```
async.waterfall([

  function(callback){
    var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/campaign";
    console.log("calling campaign");
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
      // JSON body
      if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
      campaign = JSON.parse(body);
      callback(null, restaurant)
    });
  },
  function(obj, callback){
    console.log(obj.restaurant);
    var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/restaurantByID/"+obj.restaurant;
    console.log("calling restaurant");
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
      // JSON body
      if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
      restaurant = JSON.parse(body);
      callback(null, restaurant)
    });
  }
]
```

Comment: I fixed that (please see UPDATE 1 above) but the code still does not work as expected. Thanks

Comment: Hm, are you seeing any errors logged?  Are you certain you restarted the server after making changes?

Comment: @JoeJeanJJ are you able to fix it ?